# How to loop through python dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a script that loops through the dictionary and prints keys and values separately. The code is as follows:

```
dict = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}

list1 = list(dict.keys())
list2 = list(dict.values())

i = 0

while i < len(list1)
    print(list1[0])
```

When I execute the script, `key1` prints multiple times, while I expect `key1`, `key2` to be printed.

Comment: This has an assortment of issues, you `while` without incrementing `i` (infinite loop), you index `list1` using the same value (same key printed), you don't have `:` after the while statement (`SyntaxError`). I linked the appropriate way to loop through a dictionary, you'll find it is way better to use a `for i in dictionary` construct.

Comment: I have been through the linked question. I used colon in my code. I don't understand why while loop is not iterating?

Comment: Morevover I am trying to pass these values to python function variables

Comment: Issue resolved now